# An alternative to Dictionary<T,T>

Tags: c#, dictionary

My application requires I print N amount of times the Value X.

So, I can do this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> toPrint = new Dictionary<int, string>();
toPrint.Add(2, "Hello World");
```

...and later on I can use this information to print 2 pages, both with the text value "Hello World".

The issue I have, is the Dictionary really wants the first value to be the Key:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

Therefore, if I want to add 2 pages with the text value "Hello World" and then another 2 with "Goodbye World" I have an issue - both of them have a TKey value of 2 and this causes a runtime error ("An item with the same key has already been added").

The logic which will causes an error:

```
Dictionary<int, string> toPrint = new Dictionary<int, string>();
toPrint.Add(2, "Hello World");
toPrint.Add(2, "Goodbye World");
```

I still need this concept/logic to work, but I obviously can't use the Dictionary type due to the Key.

Does any one have any ideas of a work around?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a List<T> will be enough in this case

```
class PrintJob
{
    public int printRepeat {get; set;}
    public string printText {get; set;}
    // If required, you could add more fields
}

List<PrintJob> printJobs = new List<PrintJob>()
{
    new PrintJob{printRepeat = 2, printText = "Hello World"},
    new PrintJob{printRepeat = 2, printText = "Goodbye World"}
}

foreach(PrintJob p in printJobs)
    // do the work
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but figured 12 people would beat me to it, so I offered up the Tuple solution.

Comment: Ah... it's always the easy solution isn't it.. here i have been looking into creating a new collection type!!! Thank you.

Comment: Note: Tuple is available starting in .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 15):

I think a Tuple would be perfect for this job.

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> toPrint = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
toPrint.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Hello World"); 
toPrint.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Goodbye World");
```

And... you could easily wrap this into a self contained class.

```
public class PrintJobs
{
  // ctor logic here


  private readonly List<Tuple<int, string>> _printJobs = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

  public void AddJob(string value, int count = 1) // default to 1 copy
  {
    this._printJobs.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(count, value));
  }

  public void PrintAllJobs()
  {
    foreach(var j in this._printJobs)
    {
      // print job
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks - Not heard of Tuple before.
More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: I think Tuples are exactly here so we don't have to create specific class just to hold a Pair of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionaries, but the key should be the string, not the int; that's what is unique after all!

That said, you're not doing look-ups so a dictionary is inappropriate. Steve's answer is likely best in this situation though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you have couple of options here...

1.) in your scenario it seems the string itself is the key, so you can just reverse the order of your parameters

```
new Dictionary<string, int> ()
```

2.) use Tuple or even a custom class/struct if it makes sense in your situation. Usage of tuple Chris has already shown you, so I'll show you the "class solution" I have in mind.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyTextToPrint { get;set; }
    public string NumberOfPrints { get;set; }
    // any other variables you may need
}
```

and then just create a List of these classes, works pretty much the same as Tuple, it's just a more standardized way of doing this, because maybe you will need same the functionality on other places as well or maybe want to manipulate the data further.